# An example of a weak uniform Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I need to prove a fixed point result using Meir's and Keeler's fixed point Theorem. My goal is to use such a weak uniform Lipschitz condition (which is not necessarily Lipschitz uniform). My question is about a function of type: $f: (X,d)\longrightarrow (X,d) $ such that
$$ (\star) \quad d(f(x),f(y)) \leq L d(x,y)^2, \; x,y \in X  $$
for any complete metric space $(X,d)$ even if $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$.
Note that under the condition $ (\star) $ we may establish a fixed point result using Meir's and Keeler's Theorem (with a special choice of $L$ of course).

My question is about functions of type $(\star)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the condition $(\ast )$ then $$|f' (x)| =\lim_{h\to 0} \left|\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)|}{h}\right| \leq \lim_{ h\to 0} L|h| =0$$
Therefore $f'(x) =0$ fol all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ an hence $f$ is constant function.

Comment: Thank you very much @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura , this is true if the function is everywhere differentiable on $R$ ? May we expect another example (or counter-example) without any differentiability assumption ?

Comment: No it is true for all functions satisfying the condition. In the above I never use the assumption that $f$ is differentiable, the differentiability follows from the ineqalities.

Comment: Yes of course! this is obvious, any function of such type is everywhere differentiable. Thank you again. But far from $R$ can we expect to  find functions of such type ?